# An ambiguos part of DKIM specification about header hash

Tags: email, dkim

I'm trying to sign email messages according to DKIM specification. I'm reading [RFC 6376](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376) and see there relatively straight way to create the signature, but there is a problematic part about DKIM-Signature header's tag b.

As I understand, it's value should be a base64 encoded signature of a hash, that is calculated against selected message headers, including DKIM-Signature, but without a value of the tag b. If it's correct, then I have some trouble understanding RFC here:

> The header field MUST be presented to the hash algorithm after the
> body of the message rather than with the rest of the header fields

Here the RFC speaks about DKIM-Signature header. The text is from the chapter "3.7.  Computing the Message Hashes".

If I understand it correctly, then it means I must calculate a hash of a block, which includes full message body, with the DKIM-Signature header appended to it's end (variant 1). But as I read in other sources, including answers here, it seems (because there's no clear algorithm in other sources) that DKIM-Signature header should be appended to the end of a list of message headers, that are selected for the hashing (variant 2). Then the ambiguity is: which variant is correct?

And finally, after 2 hashes are calculated, should I sign the second hash (hash of headers after disambiguation of a correct variant), as it seems things should work, or should I sign just the list of selected (and canonicalized) headers?

A common sense tells me that variant 2 should be the actual choice, and signature should be applied to the second hash, but I'm in doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-code for the signature algorithm in [RFC 6376](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.7) is wrong. It was corrected in [Errata 5252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5252):

```
   body-hash    =  hash-alg (canon-body, l-param)
   data-hash    =  hash-alg (h-headers, D-SIG)
   signature    =  sig-alg (d-domain, selector, data-hash)
```

What it means is that you first hash the canonicalized message body up to the length specified in the `l` parameter and then include this hash in the `bh` tag of the `DKIM-Signature` header field. Afterwards, you start a new hash with the header fields as specified in the `h` tag and canonicalized according to the `c` tag (an empty string is included for non-existent header fields, so that adding these header fields later on invalidates the DKIM signature) followed by the `DKIM-Signature` header field which you are about to add without the `b` tag. The resulting hash is the one you sign. This means that your second variant is the correct one.

Comment: Ok, at least I have your word against appending DKIM-Signature after message body.

Comment: However, I have sent test messages to some test servers (appmaildev.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.5.9600.16384 and mail-tester.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)) and both tell that my attempt with signed headers, instead of signed header hash, is correct. Also I have seen some other messages, from reliable mail services, where correct verification possible only if the headers are signed, but not the hash of headers. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we're talking about the same things. Just to be sure: The `DKIM-Signature` header field can appear anywhere in the header of the message, which comes before the body, but new header fields are typically added at the top of the header section. What you compute is, somewhat simplified `b=sign(hash(canonicalized headers according to h tag, to be added DKIM-Signature header with empty b tag and bh=hash(body))`. In Nodemailer, the DKIM signing code looks [like this](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/368f545753b92f1954c0c98c5f151ac38afb1f0d/lib/dkim/sign.js#L31-L48).

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please provide some (pseudo-)code of what you mean by "signed headers" versus "signed header hash". Signatures are always computed for a hash of the data that you want to sign. If you use a library, it might hash the data for you. In such a case, you have to make sure that the data isn't hashed twice, of course, so you leave the hashing to the library. If other email servers accept your signature as valid, you're already doing everything correctly.

Comment: Actually, the answer is in your comment. I use Java's java.security.Signature and it is not clear from documentation if it hashes provided data first or not. But, as you say, it is very probable that in fact there is some hidden hashing operation within the sign method.

Comment: But if you press for upvoting your answer then could you please provide a source for the information from your comment: "Signatures are always computed for a hash of the data".

Comment: And one more point. If it is true that "Signatures are always computed for a hash of the data", then what is the point in talking about a hash in RFC? It's just useless information if any signature is always computed for a hash. Why there is such useless (and misleading) information?

Comment: And just to make the subject clear: I asked about quoted sentence from RFC, next you answered about pseudocode changes in RFC, but there is no errata for this RFC, except the pseudocode, that is concerned with signing algorithm. It means that the RFC still recommends to do something weird (if I understand it correctly). However, your pointing to erratas makes clear for me that mistakes in RFC are common and I can use my working code just as is, because everybody else uses the same algorithm, despite any discrepancies in RFC.

Comment: I agree that the [documentation of `java.security.Signature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) isn't great in this regard, but it clearly speaks about message digest algorithms at the top. Moreover, the identifiers for signature algorithms include the hash algorithm that is being used, such as `SHA256withRSA`.

Comment: [Here is a source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#Method) for the fact that signatures are always computed for a hash of the data: "There are several reasons to sign such a hash (or message digest) instead of the whole document. [Efficiency, compatibility, and integrity]" You see the same if you check actual signature schemes, such as [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Signing_messages) or [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm).

Comment: Why does the RFC talk about hashes? Because for a signature scheme to work, the signer and the verifier have to use bit-for-bit exactly the same data. Specifying how to feed the data into a message digest (= hashing) algorithm is the main task of a standard which specifies a signing and verification procedure. Unfortunately, this particular RFC failed its main task, which is rather embarrassing. That its pseudo-code doesn't coincide with the API of your particular library isn't its fault, though.

Comment: Yes, errors in RFCs are shockingly common. Make it a habit to always check the corresponding errata. The sentence that you quoted confuses me as well, which is why I opted for the more formal definition in my response. Feel free to open an erratum for this particular sentence, but don't expect to get it resolved. For what it's worth, [here's a list of errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?submitter_name=Kaspar+Etter) that I submitted while writing [this article about email](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/).

Comment: I appreciate your work (and your article, which looks really good because it collects a lot of useful information in one place).

Comment: But a little correction should be made about " bit-for-bit exactly the same data". The "exactness" property is ensured using canonicalization algorithm, which is more clearly defined in the RFC in comparison with the signing procedure.